# Minimizing the following function, only getting impossible values.

Tags: calculus, vectors

$|F_R|=\sqrt{ (16+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}x)^2 + (\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}x)^2 }$

I am trying to minimize x, which is the magnitude of another vector.

Then I square both sides to simplify it

$$g(x)=|F_R|^2=16^2+16\sqrt{2}x+x^2$$

Now I need to minimize the function, so I find the critical points of the derviative of $g(x)$

$$g'(x)=0=2x+16\sqrt{2}$$

$$x=-11.3$$

The correct answer in the book is $11.3$ for the magnitude of the vector x.  My answer is practically the same, except negative.  Magnitudes can't be negative.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: The magnitude of your answer is $11.3$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese But $x$ is supposed to be the magnitude of a vector, so $x$ cannot be negative.

Comment: My guess is that your initial formulation of $F_R$ is not correct, maybe it is $(16 - $ instead of a $(16 + $?

Comment: I bet the same, since $(16+x/\sqrt{2})^2+x^2/2$ is an increasing function over $\mathbb{R}^+$, giving a minimum value for $|F_R|$ equal to $16$.